# How to edit video player props in React Native Video using ref

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video. I am trying to change the props for each video onPress, which are in a FlatList of videos.  So if I use state it will change all the video props in the entire FlatList, whereas I only want to change the one.

I created: `const videoPlayer = []` and added a ref in each Video player like: `ref={r => videoPlayer[item.id] = r}`, and I know I can do `videoPlayer[item.id].presentFullscreenPlayer()` to play the video in fullscreen because it is a method of the player, but what about controlling other properties like `resizeMode` and `paused`?

I have tried `videoPlayer[item.id].props.paused = false`, but that has no effect. I also imagine I can create some sort of complex object in state, but then the entire list will update every time I change a property and that may cause slow running refreshes in a big list.

So, is there I way I can control props of each video like I explained?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely could use `setNativeProps` like:

`videoPlayer[item.id].setNativeProps({
    paused: false
  })`

This is a doc page about it: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!